# Modifying TypeScript symbol using compiler API

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to use the TypeScript compiler API (1.4) to rename symbols across source files, for example renaming a global variable and all references to it. I started with the [instructions here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API-%28TypeScript-1.4%29), then I used this to get all identifiers

```
function getNodes(sf: ts.SourceFile): ts.Node[]
{
    var nodes: ts.Node[] = [];
    function allNodes(n: ts.Node)
    {
        ts.forEachChild(n, n => { if (n.kind == ts.SyntaxKind.Identifier) nodes.push(n); allNodes(n); return false; })
    };
    allNodes(sf);
    return nodes;
}
```

Once you create your type checker, you can then resolve your nodes (where every reference to the identifier has a separate instance) into symbols (where references to the same variable have the same instance):

```
var checker = program.getTypeChecker(true);
var symbols = getNodes(sourceFile).map((n, i, array) => checker.getSymbolAtLocation(n));
```

Great. But now I am stuck, since the symbol seems to be immutable. Are you supposed to clone it and then provide some kind of lookup table to the emitter? Or a custom SymbolWriter, or SymbolDisplayBuilder? I can't see many extension points in the classes.

Comment: did you find a way to do that? I was able to rename it, but dealing with the SourceFile type kinda sucks because when we use the ts printer to print the file, it removes all the new lines.

Answer (score 3):

> for example renaming a global variable and all references to it.

Symbols have declarations stored inside them (some docs https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/overview/binder/binder-declarations)

You can get access to these using `let declarations = symbol.getDeclarations();` and in fact that is exactly what `getRenameInfo` in `services.ts` does ([source code](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ntypescript/blob/b5073fb9defcf7bd4c3e61f08ab36c2c7953b5d2/src/services/services.ts#L4286)).